# How to create a new variable by pasting one variable below the other?

Tags: r

Fellow statisticians/programmers,

I have a simple problem. I have two variables, x1 and x2 and I want to combine these to to get the variable x3, as below:

```
x1   x2    x3

1    5     1
2    4     2
3    4     3
1    6     1
           5
           4
           4
           6
```

Probably this is just a simple function, but I really cannot find the right command.

Can somebody please help me? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As Andrie says in the comments, use the function [c()](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Vectors-and-assignment).  To initialize all three vectors as you wish, printing x3 at the end:

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3,1)
x2 <- c(5,4,4,6)
x3 <- c(x1,x2)
print(x3)
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you wanna process this in a matrix look up the functions rbind(), this will bind rows, and cbind(), this will bind columns.

If you have a more complex data frame you may use melt() from the "reshape2" package.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic solution for `matrix` or `data.frame`:

```
m <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
d <- as.data.frame(m)

as.vector(m)
unlist(d)
```